# Is there a way to remember the last used account using Android Account Manager?

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.android, accountmanager

I currently store the last user's info in SharedPreferences, but can Account Manager handle this function too?  I have a few different apps that all use the same account on the phone, but I do not know the best way to automatically log in the most recent user.

Comment: Could you elaborate the scenario? If it's simple username/password authentication, I recommend using the `SharedPreferences`. The `AccountManger` has it's own set of APIs and quite a work to set it up

Comment: I already have an account manager up and running, and am saving the user details in SharedPreferences. I was just wondering if Account manager itself had that functionality. Or what the "best practice" is. Google mentions remembering the last user in their documentation but they don't say the best method to use. It seems like shared preferences is right. I just need to make a centralized shared preferences between apps.